# How to change "JoanZapata/android-pdfview" package name in android studio

Tags: android

I'm working with PDFViewer to view a pdf within my app and I loaded a test pdf that displays rather successfully. But how to change package name https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview with this android PDFViewer.

Please advice how can i rename the package.

Comment: right click on package and go to refactor then select rename, enter you new package name and save it

Comment: Firstly,download the source code of this project instead of using a jar.Secondly,right click the package that you want to rename and choose **Refactor-Rename** to change its name.

Comment: I tried many times (Right click the package that you want to rename and choose Refactor-Rename to change its name), but it does not work "https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview" in this android application. Please anyone advice how can i rename the package.